# Is this IIS configuration possible, and if not, what would you suggest?

Tags: asp.net, iis, authentication

Is it possible to configure an IIS website to provide domain credentials to an ASP.Net application if the user is logged into a particular domain, and use anonomous if they are coming in from the internet?

Will I need seperate virtual directories, one with domain only and one with Anon only?

I have an application follows different code paths depending on wether or not the user is autenticated against the intranet domain, but also need to allow login attempts from outsite the intranet, so the site itself is hosted outside of the intranet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like if anon access is on it will only use that, and I will need to setup two virtual directories.